# How to find CPU utilization rate moster file?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I use "top" command and got the result below:
  PID USER  PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM  TIME+   COMMAND
30769 test  20   0 48964  23m 5968 R  100  1.4   2:06.89 php
30747 test  20   0 48964  23m 5976 R   57  1.4   6:24.55 php

How can I to find which php file use the mostest CPU.
(apologize for my poor english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ps -e -o pid,%cpu,comm= | sort -n -k 2 | grep "\.php"
```

output will be sorted by processes `%CPU` usage.

Comment: Thanks,I use this command:ps H -eo user,pid,ppid,tid,time,%cpu,cmd --sort=%cpu the "cmd" show me that the php file whick I looking for.
Now I have another probem:I found that some php file IO is to hight in read.How can I do to make the IO down?

Comment: @hui314 it all depends on the script, which is run.

Comment: The php scrip include some another php file,maybe is the another php scrip cause the IO problem?It is that possible?

Comment: @hui314 yes, it's possible.